# How to get and display all child objects in parent serializer in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-generic-views, django-serializer

I have 3 different serializers for 3 different views of parent as well as child object. The views are `CreateAPIView`, `ListAPIView`, `RetrieveAPIView`.

So my `CreateAPIView` has one serializer for creating an object, `ListAPIView` has one serializer for listing the objects, and `RetrieveAPIView` has one for showing the object's details. And this is true for child as well as for parent object.

How do I list all the child objects in the parent object that are related to it?
That means in `RetrieveAPIView` of parent I want to show `ListAPIView`  of its children.

**models**:

```py
class Boards(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Boards, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Lists(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    board = models.ForeignKey(Boards, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Lists, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers:**

```py
class BoardCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    # user = request.user
    class Meta:
        model = Boards
        fields = ['name']

class BoardListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name = 'trello:board-detail',
        lookup_field = 'slug',
    )
    user = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Boards
        fields = ['url', 'name', 'user']

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)

class BoardDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Boards
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'user']

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)
```

And similarly, I've serializers for lists as well.(`boards- parent object, lists-children`).

How do I show all the lists in the detail view of `Boards` that are related to it?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by parent and children? can you show your models and serializers so we can understand the relationships between them? nested serializers maybe what you need but I can't say for sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways you can do this:

1. Use the `source` argument by adding this field to `BoardDetailSerializer`:

   ```
   class BoardDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
       user = SerializerMethodField()
       lists = ListSerializer(
           source='Lists_set',
           many=True
       )
       class Meta:
           model = Boards
           fields = ['id', 'name', 'user', 'lists']

       def get_user(self, obj):
           return str(obj.user.username)
   ```
2. You can also use `SerializerMethodField()` the same way you did for user. In the method, you need to pass the list through the serializer and obtain the data which will be in json format(assuming you're using the default json renderer)

Comment: I already had tried the second method you told, it gave some Json type error,tried to solve that too but didn't work.

Comment: @Ken4cholars  
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
rest_framework\serializers.py", line 118, in __init__
    super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: @user10058776 Yes please remove the queryset argument. It shouldn't be there

Comment: and what does source argument specify? What shout be my 'Lists_set' ?

Comment: it's the related_name from Board back to Lists. If not specified Django names it as `<model_name>_set`. That's why it is `Lists_set`. Generally, the source specifies the name of the model attribute to fetch for that field in the serializer

Comment: it further gave: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `lists` on serializer `BoardDetailSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Boards` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Boards' object has no attribute 'Lists_set'.

Comment: Is `Lists` the correct name of the model? if not, it will not work. it may be better to explicitly specify the related name in the foreign key and use that. Read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Hey, the model name was 'Lists' only, but don't know how it didn't work.But I just changed the related name in models, and it worked. Ican not thank you enough! Thank you so much for sticking with me through this! I'm new and confused how actually the data/control is passed back and forth between these class based views and serializers..If you have something that will help me understand it, do share. Thank you again!

Comment: @user10058776 I'm glad I was able to help. I do recommend you to read the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org. It's almost like a tutorial of it's own. Again, look at the framework's source code for any particular method or class you don't understand. I do this a lot and it helps. Any normal IDE should allow you look at the code of libraries you're using. You should also check out this section of the site https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/tutorials-and-resources/ and pick one of the books and check out the tutorials listed. 
Goodluck!